# Java UDP p2p chatprogram.

Tags: java, udp, chat, p2p

im making a P2P chat program. for this i use UDP datagrams. but im having some problems.

sometimes the program works without any problems. but most of the times only 1 of the 2 people recieve the message or sometimes neither of the 2 people get a message. im thinking about going to TCP but i want to keep it P2P so no central server.

my code:

```
package herexChatProg;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import login.MainScreen;

public class MessageSender extends Thread {
private int Port;
private String recIP;
private final static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(System.in));

private MainScreen Screen;

private DatagramSocket ds = null;
private DatagramPacket dp = null;

public MessageSender(MainScreen m, String ip, int port) throws Exception {
    recIP = ip;
    Port = port;
    Screen = m;
    System.out.println("chat program: IP address: " + recIP + " port " + Port);
    start();

}

public void run() {
    try {
        // open DatagramSocket to receive
        ds = new DatagramSocket(Port);
        // loop forever reading datagrams from the DatagramSocket
        while (true) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[65000]; // max char length
            dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            ds.receive(dp);
            String s = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());

            Screen.writeText(s);
            // System.out.println("UDP datagram length " + s.length() + "
            // from IP " + dp.getAddress() + " received: " + s);
        }
    } catch (SocketException se) {
        System.err.println("chat error (Socket Closed = good): " + Se.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please check your connection or try to log on again");
        } catch (IOException se) {
        System.err.println("chat error: " + se.getMessage());
    }
}

public void Stop() {
    if (ds != null) {
        ds.close();
        ds = null;
    }
}



public boolean sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
    try {
        System.out.println("Sending to " + recIP + " socket " + Port + " data: " + message);
        byte[] data = message.getBytes();
        DatagramSocket theSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket theOutput = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, InetAddress.getByName(recIP), Port);
        theSocket.send(theOutput);
        Screen.writeText(message);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

if any of you spot the problem or can help me that would be great

thanks DenTilloZie

Comment: UDP is unreliable, you can't be sure a message arrives, but in a chat program that's not the desired behaviour... To solve this you will have to implement TCP like mechanisms on top of UDP so you can be sure a message arrived (if not resend it). But then you're reinventing the wheel. I would just use TCP, this won't change much to the code and you are sure that **all** messages arrive.

Comment: P2P is not mutually exclusive with TCP, each client can also act as a server. You could simulate connectionless communications (and keep things simple - message boundaries) by only sending/receiving one message per connection.

Comment: i have been looking into this but they all seem to work with central server. could you help me with what i should change to make it tcp?

Answer (score 1):

> if any of you spot the problem or can help me that would be great

The "problem" of not all messages reaching their destination is normal, it's because UDP is unreliable. It isn't due to your code (well due to the fact you're using UDP instead of TCP).

If you want to be sure that each message arrives at its destination you have 2 possibilities. You could use TCP instead of UDP as TCP guarantees each message arrive (and guarantees even more). If you really want to continue with UDP you will have to send an acknowledge (to the original sender of the message) when receiving a message. When a sender receives the acknowledge he can be sure the message arrived at its destination. However there are a lot of extra problems you should fix if you use UDP (message order, ...). So i would just recommend to use TCP instead of reinventing the wheel.

> im thinking about going to TCP but i want to keep it P2P so no central server.

This will be hard to achieve. There are different possibilities for implementing a Peer-to-peer system :

- With a central coordinater
- By flooding
- By distributed hash tables

The first approach is the simplest but is not possible as you explicitly want no central server. But the other approaches are considerably more difficult.